# Socket.io - Is there a way to save socketid to prevent a new one being generated

Tags: express, socket.io

After a connection to the socket.io server a socket.id is given for the connection. When the socket connection has not been used after some time a new socket id is generated.

I have read a lot of tutorials that do a "hello world" connection that just gets you connected, but, there is not much literature on messaging peer-to-peer/group. The docs give a 3 line paragraph on rooms/namespaces and every question related to this is just given a link to the same 3 line paragraph.

I understand that you can create and object/array of chats(in this example). For this example, let's say it is an object. That Object looks something like this:

```
const connections = {
  "randomSocketID1": { 
    recipient: "Mom",
    messages: [Array of Objects]
    //more information
    }
}
```

I then send a message to `randomSocketID1` --> 'Hello'. Then next day I want to send another message to "Mom". Is that socketID going to be the same *OR AT LEAST* will "randomSocketID1" be updated under the hood, to its updated ID(which sounds improbable)? Is the regeneration of the socketID a product of garbage collection or a socket/engine/websocket protocol?

thanks for any clarification

Answer (score 1):

So I was still unable to find an actual answer to this and by the 0 responses i see that no one knows. So what I have done in order to make sure that user and socket id are maintained is whenever a user enters the component that connects to the socketio server an automatic 'update-user' is emitted and the back end then just finds the user and assigns it the value.

So I have something like this:

chat.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.socket.emit('update-user', 'Ctfrancia');
}
```

then in the back end:

```
const users = {};

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('update-user', user => {
    if (user in users) users[user] = socket.id;
    else users[user] = socket.id
  });
});
```